# What does ">>>" mean in Python examples?

Tags: python

This might seem to be too simple but it isn't explicitly mentioned anywhere.

I see the symbol `">>>"` in many Python sample codes. (Eg: [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html))

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default appearance of the prompt in `python` interpreter, as described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode):

> When commands are read from a tty, the interpreter is said to be in
>   interactive mode. In this mode it prompts for the next command with
>   the primary prompt, usually three greater-than signs (`>>>`); for
>   continuation lines it prompts with the secondary prompt, by default
>   three dots (`...`).

Documentation generally follows the style of the interpreter, displaying an expression prefixed by `>>>`, followed by the resulting value on the next line, with no prefix.

It's not valid Python code. You can't put it in the `.py` file -- that would be a syntax error. It's like `$` in `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

The `>>>` is the standard Python prompt.  It is used by IDLE and by Python interactively (just type `python` on the command-line).

It is used in documentation as an "invitation to type", but also to indicate user input, `doctest` is a module that uses it, for example.

Answer (score 3):

In code samples the >>> indicates that this is code that you must put in your self to differentiate from the returned results. Therefore the following code sample:

```
 >>>print "Hello World"
 Hello World
```

Indicates that the line beginning >>> is what you must enter to receive the output of Hello World

Answer (score 1):

>>> is the prompt of an interactive Python session where you can type your commands. This is why it occurs at the beginning of a line. >>> is not a valid Python operator and you shouldn't type the prompt into your programs.